# encoding issue on some pages (json files) served by github pages

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I have an encoding issue on this repository: https://github.com/franceimage/franceimage.github.io

1/ Accents are wrong when I display https://franceimage.github.io/json/youtube.json in my browser (served by github)

[image]

2/ However, accents are right when I display the same page but run it served locally (jekyll serve)

[image]

3/ Accents are right on the html pages (served by github pages)

[image]

Can somebody explain what is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call **json/youtube.json** :

- Locally, you get a `Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8` response header.
- From github pages, you get `Content-Type:application/json`.
- Transmitted files are identical.

As [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) states : "*JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode. The default encoding is UTF-8.*"

It seems that browsers are not falling back to utf-8 when they receive a `Content-Type:application/json` response header.

An idea can be to submit this question to Jekyll/Github pages community. Maybe you can introduce a feature request in order to get Github pages sending encoding header.

[Jekyll talk](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/) can be a good entry point for such a question.

Comment: I see. So, I just have to download the json file instead of copy/paste what I see in the browser.